C# Await/Async with a delegate vs direct await call - are the two approaches functionally equivalent?
Can anyone advise me if the two code snippets are functionally equivalent in .NET 8?
If not, why not?
FIRST SNIPPET

    Task<ICollection<SearchResults>> getResultTask = _aRepo.List(request.AParam, request.PageIndex, request.PageSize);

    if (request.PageIndex != null && request.PageSize != null)
    {
       int totalRecords = await _myRepo.CountAsync();
       // store totalrecords (non-async)
    }


    ICollection<SearchResults> results = await getResultTask;

SECOND SNIPPET:
    if (request.PageIndex != null && request.PageSize != null)
    {
       int totalRecords = await _myRepo.CountAsync();
       // store totalrecords (non-async)
    }

    // Is this functionally equivalent to the above?
    ICollection<SearchResults> results = await _aRepo.List(request.AParam, request.PageIndex, request.PageSize);


Why does _aRepo.List return a different type in each snippet?

the first one creates the task and awaits it later, so you can do some other stuff in between. The second one directly awaits the task. So no, they are not equivalent.

@JohnathanBarclay because I made a mistake - I copied from actual working code and needed to make changes as not to violate any company rules. I'll update

@Fildor have corrected to return same types.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain whether or not the task is created beforehand and assigned to a variable then awaited, or task created by the await, is the execution not going to be the same? ie: the task in the delegate is still going to be awaited after the call to _myRepo.CountAsync() - it won't be parallel?

" it won't be parallel?" - you mean concurrent? If you want to make sure it isn't, I'd recommend the second approach.

@Fildor Would it be concurrent using the first approach? Putting a task into a variable doesn't, as far as I am aware, make it behave differently when awaited?  As far as I can see, putting the task into a variable then awaiting it, as above in #1, is identical in code behaviour to awaiting for the task in #2.  The count will be awaited first, then the call to the repo will be awaited. So I'm not seeing any real benefit to putting it in a variable in these particular cases. The compiler might even move the variable closer to its first usage in release mode?

This isn't about the variable. The task starts inside the List method, when the first true asynchronous call is made. await just awaits an already existing task to complete, it doesn't make it run. Parallel, concurrent and asynchronous are all different concepts. If your repository code tries to use the same connection or DbContext concurrently from different threads you'll get concurrency exceptions even though the ExecuteAsync or ToListAsync operations are asynchronous, ie non-blocking.

This means that if _myRepo and _aRepo wrap the same connection or DbContext, the first snippet can throw an exception if CountAsync starts executing its query before List had a chance to complete. That would be a coding bug by the way, not an issue with DbConnection or DbContext.

FYI - there are methods handling various cases of multiple task eg. Task.WhenAll ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-8.0 )

Consider the following code:
static async Task method1()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}

static async Task method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}

Now if you call that from a console app like so:
public static async Task Main()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var task1 = method1(); // Starts method1() without waiting for it to return.

    await method2();  // Starts method2() and waits for it to return.
    await task1;      // Wait for method1() to return.

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed); // Will be approximately 3s - the longer of the two method times.
    Console.ReadLine();
}

This will output a time of around 3s, because method1() has been started AND NOT AWAITED before method2() is started and awaited.
method1() will take around 2s and method2() will take around 3s, so the overall time will be the longer of those two times.
Now see what happens if you do this:
public static async Task Main()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await method1(); // Starts method1() and waits for it to return.
    await method2(); // Starts method2() and waits for it to return.

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed); // Will be approximately 5s - the sum of the two method times.
    Console.ReadLine();
}

This will output around 5s, because the method1() is started and awaited, taking around 2s to complete. Only after that is method2() started and awaited, which takes around 3s to complete.
Therefore the overall time is 5s (as compared to 3s for the first example).

Right, that explains it. Thank you!
